# How to change language in remix-i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, remix

I am using Remix with remix-i18next. I would like to create a button to change the language in the page but I don't know how to do it.

I know that the hook useChangeLanguage will change the language to the one defined in the loader and the locale obtained in the loader can be obtained from the request:

```
import { useChangeLanguage } from "remix-i18next";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import i18next from "~/i18next.server";

export async function loader({ request }: LoaderArgs) {
  let locale = await i18next.getLocale(request);
  return json({ locale });
}

export let handle = {
  // In the handle export, we can add a i18n key with namespaces our route
  // will need to load. This key can be a single string or an array of strings.
  // TIP: In most cases, you should set this to your defaultNS from your i18n config
  // or if you did not set one, set it to the i18next default namespace "translation"
  i18n: "common",
};

export default function Root() {
  // Get the locale from the loader
  let { locale } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  let { i18n } = useTranslation();

  // This hook will change the i18n instance language to the current locale
  // detected by the loader, this way, when we do something to change the
  // language, this locale will change and i18next will load the correct
  // translation files
  useChangeLanguage(locale);

  return (
    <html lang={locale} dir={i18n.dir()}>
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Outlet />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

However, I would like to be able to change the language and not use the language defined in the request. I only want to use the language defined in the request if the user didn't define the language.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to have have an onclick handler or something similar setup:

```
onClick={() => changeLanguage("de")
```

Next step is to check your setup. Have this in your component

```
let { t , i18n } = useTranslation();
```

Make sure you're not using any namespace in the step above.
eg.

> let { t , i18n } = useTranslation("translations");

this somehow prevents the code from working.

Add this handler inside your component:

```
  const changeLanguage = (language) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(language, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert(language)
    });
  };
```

In your component:

```
<span>{t("welcome")}</span>
```

You should see the language change instantly depending on your setup translations. feel free to remove the alert.